# How to retrieve the date from a MongoDB ObjectId using SQL

Tags: sql, mongodb

In MongoDB you can retrieve the date from an ObjectId using the `getTimestamp()` function. How can I retrieve the date from a MongoDB ObjectId using SQL (e.g., in the case where such an ObjectId is stored in a MySQL database)?

Example input:

```
507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e
```

Wanted output:

```
2012-10-15T21:26:17Z
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved as follows (assuming `objectId` is a string) in MySQL:

```sql
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(
    CAST(CONV(SUBSTR(objectId, 1, 8), 16, 10) AS UNSIGNED)
) FROM table
```

It works as follows:

- `SUBSTR(objectId, 1, 8)` takes the first 8 characters from the hexadecimal `objectId` string
- `CONV(..., 16, 10)` converts the hexadecimal number into a decimal number and returns it as a string (which represents the UNIX timestamp)
- `CAST (...) AS UNSIGNED` converts the timestamp string to an unsigned integer
- `FROM_UNIXTIME(...)` converts the timestamp integer into the date

Note that by default the displayed date will be based on your system's timezone settings.

Comment: @NeilLunn, just because it's irrelevant to *you* doesn't mean others won't find it useful.

Answer (score 3):

For those using SQL Server, similar results would be generated with:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(
    SECOND,
    CAST(
        CONVERT(
            BINARY(4), '0x'+SUBSTRING(@MongoObjectId, 1, 8), 1
        ) AS BIGINT
    ),
    CAST('1970-01-01 00:00' AS DATETIME)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Redshift**

```
select timestamp 'epoch' + cast (STRTOL(left(_id,8),16) as bigint) * interval '1 second' as my_timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

## MSSQL

Building on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32822921) by Teemu

To make some easier to reuse, you can wrap it into your own scalar function like so

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.mongoCreated(@_id CHAR(24))
    RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN DATEADD(
        SECOND,
        CAST(
            CONVERT(
                BINARY(4), '0x' + SUBSTRING(@_id, 1, 8), 1
            ) AS BIGINT
        ),
        CAST('1970-01-01 00:00' AS DATETIME)
    )
END
```

## Postgres

Adapted from [another answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45992757)

```
CREATE FUNCTION mongo_timestamp(_id char(24))
    RETURNS TIMESTAMP
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN TO_TIMESTAMP(('x' || lpad(LEFT(_id, 8), 8, '0'))::BIT(32)::INT);
END ;
$$
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

Answer (score 0):

To the answers above, I'd like to provide an example for **BigQuery**

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(
  CAST(CONCAT('0x', LEFT('6238e198653c381798d93493', 8)) AS INT64) * 1000
)
```