# Get the timestamp associated with a MongoDB ObjectId in Snowflake

Tags: mongodb, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Basically I have the same question as this one
[How to retrieve the date from a MongoDB ObjectId using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454804/how-to-retrieve-the-date-from-a-mongodb-objectid-using-sql)

That is, I know how to retrieve the timestamp associated to an ObjectId using `pymongo`for example,

```
ObjectId('5d8dc6e0a26870000101c53d').generation_time
# datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 27, 8, 22, 56, tzinfo=<bson.tz_util.FixedOffset object at 0x000001C2A7F4F1C8>)
```

but I don't know how to do this with Snowflake. I have a column called `_id` containing the MongoDB ObjectIds.

How can I add a new field in my Snowflake table containing the timestamps associated to the ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, I didn't get that a MongoDB ObjectId has the create timestamp embedded in the Id.

You can decode the timestamp with this:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ObjectId, 1, 8), 'XXXXXXXX'))
FROM (SELECT '5d8dc6e0a26870000101c53d' ObjectId)

=> 2019-09-27 08:22:56.000
```

The id consists of the following parts:

1. The first 4 bytes representing the seconds since the unix epoch
2. The next 3 bytes are the machine identifier
3. The next 2 bytes consists of process id
4. The last 3 bytes are a random counter value

The list above (hinting about half the answer) taken from ["How to convert from Timestamp to Mongo ObjectID"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38629868/how-to-convert-from-timestamp-to-mongo-objectid)

---

***My old wrong answer:***

You can't retrieve a date from an object id.  The reason why your Python code example works is that you have an entire *object* that has an id and other properties including `generation_time`.

If you just extract the id property from MongoDB then you don't have the other properties.

Comment: Then how come you can do it with SQL Server as in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32822921/3301113

Comment: I got MongoDB ObjectIds totally wrong.  I've updated my answer with an actual solution