# How do I retrieve the timestamp from a mongodb object id in Athena

Tags: sql, mongodb, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have the data moved from mongodb into AWS Athena. I need to extract the timestamp from the objectId of each of the record using SQL in Athena.

I could find some examples in Postgre, Redshift etc... but not in Athena...

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454804/how-to-retrieve-the-date-from-a-mongodb-objectid-using-sql](https://stackoverflow.com)

Example input:

507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e

Wanted output in Athena:

2012-10-15T21:26:17Z

Answer (score 0):

Translating this MySQL query looks pretty manageable using corresponding functions from the [docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions.html):

```cs
select from_base(substr('507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e', 1, 8), 16);
```

Output:

```
            _col0
-----------------------------
 2012-10-15 21:26:17.000 UTC
```